# Vue returns Observer in promise.then()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to fire a vuex action in `created()` and when I receive a data, then fire new asynchronous method that fetches more data from server. When data is available I will use them in a component. Unfortunatelly I got stuck with `Observer` returned from `Promise`. I tried to change data to computed() without luck. I tried to `await` but it did not help either. The other computed property `item` works fine. I know that the `Observer` is Vue's way for reactivity but I do not know how to fix it.

```
<SeriesBarChart v-if="! inProgress" :series="series" /> // initial attempt
<SeriesBarChart v-if="! inProgress" :series="groups" /> // computed property attempt

data: () => ({
  series: [{}, {}],
  inProgress: true,
}),
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('GET_POLL', { slug: this.slug }).then(() => {
    this.runQueries(this.item._id, ['vehicles=car&vehicles=bike', 'region=PRG']); // await here did not help
  });
},
computed: {
  item() {
    return this.$store.getters.POLL;
  },
  groups() {
    return this.series;
  },
},
methods: {
  async runQueries(id, queries) {
      this.inProgress = true;
      const promises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i += 1) {
        promises.push(this.$store.dispatch('GET_POLL_VOTES', { id, query: queries[i] }));
      }
      Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
          this.series[i] = values[i].data.data;
        }
      });
      this.inProgress = false;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly is this `Observer` value blocking your intent?

Comment: I need real data to work with. The code fails later when I try to access the variable but there is Observer

Comment: Did you try `await`-ing the `Promise.all`?

Comment: Is not Promise.all().then() be equivalent to await?

Comment: Wow, it helped!

Answer (score -1):

Because Yom has not posted an answer and he even deleted his helpful comment, I will post my answer for future googlers. The reason why Vue provided the `Observer` object was a statement `this.inProgress = false;` outside of the `then` block. Following code works as expected:

```
async runQueries(id, queries) {
  this.inProgress = true;
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < queries.length; i += 1) {
    promises.push(this.$store.dispatch('GET_POLL_VOTES', { id, query: queries[i] }));
  }
  Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1) {
      this.series[i] = values[i].data.data;
    }
    this.inProgress = false;
  });
}
```